# How to implement this Flask app in Google Cloud Platform(GCP)?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

My local Flask app can call other Flask apps within it.
The directory is as follows -

```
\Flask
    \app1
         \templates
         app1.py
    \app2
         \templates
         app2.py
    \templates
    main.py
    requirements.txt
    app.yaml
```

In my local code, I used the subprocess and webbrowser modules to run the apps and then open them by specifying the port numbers within Main.py
All three have different port numbers in the local code.

For example,
for calling the child app within the parent app , my code is as follows

```
 try:
    subprocess.run("python app1/app1.py", shell=True,timeout=15)
 except:
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
```

How do I implement this in GCP?

Comment: 2 processes = 2 services. I recommend you to use Cloud Run, and to deploy each flask app in a dedicated service. And then to call them. Take care of the authentication between the 2 but it's the best way. In any case, de-intricate your code is the key for the future!